# Why does my Look Dev Mode look completely glitched?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shaders, artifacts

Today marks my first day's experience with blender. Complete newbie here. I've been following a tutorial on building simple characters and getting familiar with the work space. I noticed something right away when switching between the various modes. Wireframe, Solid, and even Render Preview modes work without a hiccup (most of the time) but when viewing Dev Mode, I get crazy artifacts, shapes and colors. This WILL happen to a fresh blank General document with all settings set to default. Switching back and forth will cause the effects to change each time I go back to Dev Mode, and eventually when switching to Render Preview Mode. Ive seen people with mostly similar problems but it seems that none of the fixes are working. I've tried tweaking light and shadow settings, and some settings under the Shading tab. The effect happens in:

Eevee engine, Look Dev Mode

Eevee engine, Render Preview Mode (Happens once I switch from LDM)

Cycles, CPU Device, Look Dev Mode

Cycles, GPU Compute Device, Look Dev Mode

I've included two images. One is a screen shot of the tutorial , and one is what my screen looks like within the same window within Blender, along with my computer's information.

So sorry if it's something simple and I've overlooked it. I gave it my best to try and solve it myself. Let me know if any more information is needed. Thank you!

[image: The Upside Down]

[image: Tutorial]

Comment: Reboot, update graphics drivers.Check for z fighting (two meshes occupying the same space) Does it occur with any other scenes?

Comment: Yeah, all drivers update automatically with each OS upgrade so I'm up to date on OS 10.12.6. Blenders requirements are 10.12 and up. So I'm good there. When it comes to scenes, this issue will happen right off the bat when loading a blank, fresh, new default document. If I open a new one, and the only button I hit is Look Dev Mode, I get these shapes. I know theres something wrong because under the shading tab, the two spheres on the bottom right hand corner are also not behaving correctly compared to the one within the tutorial. Is that how they look at default? Possibly graphics card issue?

Comment: Not sure how GFX card/drivers work on a Mac, but yes it could be that. Blender 2.8 has a openGL requirement of 3.3 https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ if your system matches that then it is time to report a bug https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports